# Angularjs - Not able to bind data with ngoptions

Tags: angularjs

I've used "ngoptions" in my html page for dropdown as below.

```
<select id="bgroup" ng-model="formData.bGroup" ng-options="bGroup.name for bGroup in bloodGroups"><br>
     <option value="">---Blood Group---</option>
</select><br>
```

And this is my code in controller

```
 $scope.formData = {};
$scope.bGroups = [
    {name:'A +ve'},
    {name:'A -ve'},
    {name:'B +ve'},
    {name:'B -ve'},
    {name:'AB +ve'},
    {name:'AB -ve'},
    {name:'O +ve'},
    {name:'O -ve'}
];
```

I am not able to bind the blood group. Except blood group every other is getting inserted into database. I am not getting where I went wrong. Could anyone help me.

Comment: What is `$scope.bloodGroups`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing `ng-options` on a property called `bloodgroups` but the array in your controller is `bGroups`.

```
ng-options="bGroup.name for bGroup in bGroups"
```

See [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/judozekazu/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Your data reference is wrong for the data you have defined. It should be like this in your controller to match your binding:

```
 $scope.formData = {
     bGroups: [
         {name:'A +ve'},
         {name:'A -ve'},
         {name:'B +ve'},
         {name:'B -ve'},
         {name:'AB +ve'},
         {name:'AB -ve'},
         {name:'O +ve'},
         {name:'O -ve'}
     ]
};
```

and in your element:

```
<select id="bgroup" ng-model="formData.bGroup" ng-options="bGroup.name for bGroup in bGroups"><br>
     <option value="">---Blood Group---</option>
</select><br>
```

Comment: That JS requires you change the ng-options to `bGroup.name for bGroup in formData.bGroups`.